# using websocket on localhost with ssl with firefox

Tags: firefox, ssl, websocket

Here's the scenario I'm working on:
We have an html5, javascript web client that is served by our website.
This client communicates with our desktop application using websockets. It's the desktop application that acts as a websocket server.
The server from which the web client is downloaded is secured with ssl.
The problem is that if the client is downloaded with ssl, firefox forces all future websocket communications to be secured with ssl.
The question is how can I an get a valid ssl certicate (self signed certificate won't do) for a server that runs on the localhost?
Is there a way to workaround this constraint?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the latest on this issue? Trying to find a solve for it now that chrome by default blocks non ssl websockets...

Answer (score 0):

I have finally purchased a certificate for one of our domains and included a SAN (subject alternative name) for localhost to the certificate.
It works fine with Firefox now.
The only downfall is that it'll work only until November 2015.

Answer (score -1):

You can basically get a certificate from any CA. However, as one states "Use of certificates containing non-unique such as reserved IP addresses or internal server names represent a risk to your environment and others. The support for issuance of certificates containing such names will be discontinued no later than November 1st 2015."

ref:
[baseline requirements](https://www.cabforum.org/Baseline_Requirements_V1.pdf)

[internal server names](https://www.globalsign.com/resources/white-paper-internal-server-names-ip-address-requirements.pdf)

Comment: If I understand well, I have 2 solutions, get a certificate for a local server name which will be valid only until November 2015. Or I can get a private root CA certificate and generate my own local server name certificate, exposing myself to the security issues described in the global sign document. As I described, we install a software on every user's machine and it acts as a server, we can not configure the DNS or the host file on every user's machine to point a local server name to a public server name.